# Euros to Electrum Wallet with FIDO U2F security?

Tags: europe

I do not find a method to buy bitcoins with my Credit/Debit cards and/or deposits in Bitfinex. 
Maybe, other options exist. 
It seems that it is not the right way, but instead I need to use some of these things here https://bitcoin.org/en/exchanges
Anycoindirect.eu accepts euros but does not provide Fido U2F security. 
Bitcoin.de and bitpanda.com seem to be also small players.

- Anycoindirect.eu - feature request email sent, but no promise about the schedule.
- Bl3p.eu - No key support there, but they promised to consider it in my feature request email and will inform about the update *soon*.
- paymium.com error `Yubikey OTP is invalid` in their system, mailed to dev.
- https://therocktrading.com/en - feature request email sent and they confirm that they are working on it but no schedule.

Other thing about the identification about the user. Why they ask it? Etc  pictures about passport, residence, ...

Bitcoin market places tried: Bitfinex, Anycoindirect.eu, Bitcoin.de, Bl3p.eu
OS: Debian 9.1 Stretch
Bitcoin wallet: Electrum 2.7.9
Keys: Yubico 4 keys